# Improving saved depth data image from TrueDepth sensor

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to save depth data from an iPad Pro's FaceId TrueDepth sensor. I have taken [this demo code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera) and have added the following code with a simple button:

```swift
    @IBAction func exportData(_ sender: Any) {
        let ciimage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: realDepthData.depthDataMap)
        
        let depthUIImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciimage)
        let data = depthUIImage.pngData()
        
        print("data: \(realDepthData.depthDataMap)")
        
        do {
            let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
            let path = directory.appendingPathComponent("FaceIdData.png");
            
            try data!.write(to: path)
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = exportMeshButton
            present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to save image")
        }
    }
```

`realDepthData` is a class property I added and that I update in `dataOutputSynchronizer`:

```swift
   func dataOutputSynchronizer(_ synchronizer: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer,
                                didOutput synchronizedDataCollection: AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection) {
        
        ...

        let depthData = syncedDepthData.depthData
        let depthPixelBuffer = depthData.depthDataMap
        
        self.realDepthData = depthData
        
        ...
    }
```

I'm able to save the image (grey scale) but I'm losing some depth information, notably in the background where all objects are fully white. You can see this in the image bellow, the wall and the second person behind are not correcly appearing (all white). If I'm not mistaken, from what I've seen in the app, I should have more information!

[image: TrueDepth capture]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only 32-bit depth makes sense – you can see image's depth setting its gamma. `.exr` and `.hdr` file formats support 32-bit. `.png` and `.jpg` are generally 8-bit. You should also consider channels order when converting.

Comment: Would you have any code examples? Can I export directly my CIImage in an `.exr` or `hdr` format? I couldn't find much information on how to do this.